# jquery http call in yii

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I'm used in using this kind of http call in jquery it works fine when I'm not using any framework. Now I'm using yii as a framework and somehow when I try this jquery.get() I keep getting a response code of 400 Bad Request. I intentionally used the alert to test if the http response would return 200 OK but I think there's a mistake in the way I'm calling the url.

I've checked my webservice and everything works fine on that level.

How can I do a http call in jquery on yii framework?

both the webservice and the file calling the webservice is located at /protected/view/registrants folder.

```
 var url = "receipt.php";

    $.get(url,{product_id:product_id},function(value){

     alert(value);

    });
```

Comment: You have to follow Yii url format which is like `index.php?controller/action`. Use `$this->createUrl('..');` to use the right action in the right controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `var url = ..` part to a valid Yii url. You probably have a controller with a function that renders the receipt.php. This is the url you should call.

You can create an url like this with:

```
CController::createUrl('/controller/youraction');
```

So in the JavaScript part this would be:

```
var url = "<?= CController::createUrl('/controller/youraction); ?>";
```

More info about the `createUrl()` part:
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#createUrl-detail

Comment: I think I can't put that on my Javascript part. it wouldn't be read because it is inside a php tags.

Comment: Is the javascript in a separate .js file? Because then you can't.. but you could echo the ouput of the `createUrl()` call and put that in the js

Comment: my javascript and php are both located on the same file

Comment: If they are both in the `.php` you can mix JS and PHP like above.

Comment: I am really new at yii and it really confuses me so please forgive me for asking stupid questions but I've tried your code and I'm getting an error 404 and the response is The system is unable to find the requested action "url" i've also tried <? echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/controller/approvedOnClick');?> and still I'm getting 404 error and the response is The system is unable to find the requested action "<".

Comment: That's ok. Looks like you're trying to call an action `url`, maybe you've quoted the JS variable? There should be a controller in your controllers folder the first part of the `createUrl` call should be the name of this controller. Then there should be an action in that controller (something like: actionApprovedOnClick) that renders the correct view, the second part should be the name of the action. So finally you would have something like `CController::createUrl('/<namecontroller>/<nameaction>')`